# How to share desktop automatically?

Tags: lync-2013

Every morning we use Lync 2013 (recently rebranded Skype for Business) to join a meeting (in the calendars tab). Always I want to share my desktop and use my webcam. Right now this takes about 10 clicks (Skype for Business made it worse). Is there any way to do it automatically?